# use Stripe.source.poll in Stripe V3 using PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've migrated from Stripe v2 to v3. However, when looking for a replacement for the `Stripe.source.poll` function, I can't seen to find one? What should I use instead in v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source polling function is deprecated and has not been included in Stripe.js v3.

Instead, Stripe recommends that you set up your own polling to query the state of the order in your own backend rather than the state of the source. Cf. https://stripe.com/docs/sources/best-practices#confirmation-page.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it